# How do I assign wordpress plugin to menu?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, menu, assign

wp-content/plugins/myplugin.php

how to assign this plugin to top level menu? E.g. menu on my website: about us contacts, services my plugin. I'm using add_menu_page but I dont know why its not working.

Comment: [add_menu_page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) works in the admin section, not in your theme

Comment: Try the guys at [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) as it's likely going to be a WordPress theme issue rather that just code :)

Comment: not issue. I've installed demo theme for testing

Comment: Sorry I meant more you'll likely get a decent answer there as people know the hooks etc required to amend your menu / theme

Answer (score 0):

I have used it, when prepare my theme. You may used it also. Put it at functions.php

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_YOURPLUGINNAME_menu_page' );

function register_YOURPLUGINNAME_menu_page(){
add_menu_page( 'PLUGIN Info', 'PLUGINNAME', 'manage_options', 'custompage', 'YOURPLUGIN_menu_page', 'dashicons-tickets' , 10 ); 
}

function YOURPLUGIN_menu_page(){
?>
<h1>TEST YOUR MIGHT :)
<?php
}
?>
```